# get all products of one category

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, json

i use this function to get all products of one category in ajax request

```
function get_products()
 {
   $cat_id = $_POST['category'];
   $args = array(
  'post_type'             => 'product',
  'post_status'           => 'publish',
  'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
  'posts_per_page'        => '12',
  'tax_query'             => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'term_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
        'terms'         => $cat_id,
        'operator'      => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy'      => 'product_visibility',
        'field'         => 'slug',
        'terms'         => 'exclude-from-catalog', // Possibly 'exclude-from-search' too
        'operator'      => 'NOT IN'
    )
 )
);
 $products = new WP_Query($args);
 echo json_encode($products);

 wp_die();
}
```

then i received data of each product but not all data of each product

```
ID: 75
post_author: "4"
post_date: "2020-04-21 08:45:26"
post_date_gmt: "2020-04-21 08:45:26"
post_content: "samsung galaxy is very attractive mobile"
post_title: "samsung galaxy"
post_excerpt: "this samsung galaxy vvvvvvvvvvvv"
post_status: "publish"
comment_status: "open" 
ping_status: "closed"
post_password: ""
post_name: "samsung-galaxy"
to_ping: ""
pinged: ""
post_modified: "2020-04-29 12:06:42"
post_modified_gmt: "2020-04-29 12:06:42"
post_content_filtered: ""
post_parent: 0
guid: "http:
menu_order: 0
post_type: "product"
post_mime_type: ""
comment_count: "1"
filter: "raw"
```

i can't find image or product price or sale price or rate

i want to get this data in the script

```
function get_div(obj)
{
console.log("heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeere");
console.log(obj.ID);
console.log(obj.post_name);
console.log(obj.regular_price);=> return undefined
}
```

what is the proplem???

Answer (score 0):

For instance, WP_Query is only for fetching standard post data. Additional data by plugins such as WC will not be fetched.

#### To do a custom query

If you would like to use a custom query, you could use [WC_Product_Query](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Query.html)

Place the following in theme's functions.php and save the javascript into a separate php file. The quick test used WC default sample products.

```
// in theme's functions.php
// before init, no products is prepared if just direct call in functions.php, so to have quick test, need to place inside a init
add_action( 'init', 'ws365398_simple_test' );
function ws365398_simple_test() {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ws365398_enqueue_scripts', 101);

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'get_products' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'get_products' );
}

// actions for ajax
function get_products()
{
    if( !empty( $_POST['category'] ) ) {
        $cat_id = $_POST['category'];
    } else {
        $cat_id = 19; // default change to yours, in the test case ensure it have something by default
    }

    $args = array(
        'status'           => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'posts_per_page'        => '12',
        'tax_query'             => array(
            'relation'          => 'AND', // relation of 2 taxonomy queries
            array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                'field'         => 'term_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
                'terms'         => $cat_id,
                'operator'      => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'product_visibility',
                'field'         => 'slug',
                'terms'         => 'exclude-from-catalog', // Possibly 'exclude-from-search' too
                'operator'      => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    );
    $query = new WC_Product_Query($args);
    $products = $query->get_products();

    // convert to array data before pushing to json
    $product_arr = [];
    foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
        $product_arr[] = $product->get_data();
    }

    // echo json_encode($product_arr);
    wp_send_json_success( $product_arr ); // with success flag and use directly

    wp_die();
}

// enqueue ajax script
function ws365398_enqueue_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('test-custom-scripts', get_theme_file_uri('ws365398-test-ajax.php'), array(), 't' . time(), true);
}
```

```
<?php

// ws365398-test-ajax.php
/** Load WordPress Bootstrap */
// change to your path
require_once( '/project/wp-load.php' );

header("Content-type: text/javascript");?>

function test_ajax() {
    let myData = {
      action: 'my_action',
    };

    jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>', myData, function (response) {

      if (response.success == true) {
        console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

To test, just prepare the above files with corrected path for your environment.
Run `test_ajax()` in browser inspector and you will see something like the following:

[image]

Comment: i get the data of the product in script not in single product page

Comment: I have just updated the answer for your function, you could use `WC_Product_Query` to query products. I have just tried and it should work the way you expect

Comment: can't work it make error in script in 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Which variable is wrong in the error message? Since I have updated twice, the first copy & paste was wrong and I have fixed it immediately. the first update was `// $cat_id = $_POST['category'];` which is wrong, it should be `$cat_id = $_POST['category'];` Is this the error message you have seen? And your `$_POST['category']` is getting from a form, right? If it is not passing from a form, it will be undefined. I suggest you add a checking, the example code is updated

Comment: @OmniaMagd I have updated your function, to get_product, need to use the query method instead and I have added comments to some of the arguments.

Comment: i make loop on the returned products in my javascript code by data.length 
when i add ($query = new WC_Product_Query($args); // <--- use wc query instead
    $products = $query->get_products(); // get product method)
 error in script in Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107375/discussion-between-omnia-magd-and-simongcc).

Comment: Ok, I have added the test to the chat room and will update the answer also